# How to get partitions offset in Kafka rest proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, get

Kafka rest Api example request like below:

```
GET /consumers/testgroup/instances/my_consumer/offsets HTTP/1.1
Host: proxy-instance.kafkaproxy.example.com
Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json, application/vnd.kafka+json, application/json
{
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "test",
      "partition": 0
    },
    {
      "topic": "test",
      "partition": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

how to request this api.
For me, the puzzle is how does the get method place a body, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

cURL allows to do that:

```
curl -v 'http://kafka-rest:8082/consumers/myGroup/instances/myInstance/offsets' \
  -X GET \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json' \
  -d '{"partitions": [{"topic": "myTopic", "partition": 0}, {"topic": "myTopic", "partition": 1}]}'
```

Note: you should use only 'application/vnd.kafka.v2+json' conent type, otherwise you will get 400 Bad Request